# Вывод переменной в другую переменную с текстом Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть переменная `basename` она имеет постоянно изменяющийся текст  к примеру `text` есть другая переменная `convert` . Как передать значение переменной `basename` в переменную `convert` и прибавить к нему окончание `.png`.
В итоговом виде это должно выглядить так

```
print (convert)
text.png
```

Comment: `'{}.png'.format(basename)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
convert = '{}.png'.format(basename)
```